# Split array of strings and put each string on a flow-file-attribute in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I try to extract each element from the `frequentlyBoughtTogether` array and put it on a flow-attribute:

```
{
   frequentlyBoughtTogether: ["a","b","c"]
}
```

Frist step: **SplitJson**

[image]

Second step: **EvaluateJsonPath** to make each element a flow-file-attribute:

[image]

However this gives me following error:

[image]

When I log the failure, I can see the element in the flow-file-content, but I need it to be an attribute. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **ExtractText processor** instead of `EvaluateJsonPath` processor.

- in case of `EvaluateJsonPath` processor evaluates the flowfile content if the content is not a valid json then processor routes the `flowfile to failure`)
- In case of `Extract Text` processor just **extracts the content of the flowfile** by applying the regex.
  **ExtractText configs:**
  [image]
  Add new property as

**val**

```
(.*)
```

Then processor adds new attribute names `val` to the flowfile by **extracting the flowfile content** as value.

**Flow:**

```
SplitJson->ExtractText
```